# DropDownListFor(...) selecting boolean false by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have typical YesNo kind of dropdown in the application. For that, I have developed model (rather ViewModel Utility) class for future extension prupose.

```
public string Text { get; set; } // represents text part
        public bool Value { get; set; } // represent value
        public List<DropDown> DropDowns { get; set; } //list for binding
        public void BuildYesNoDropDown()
        {
            DropDowns = new List<DropDown>();
            DropDowns.Add(new DropDown { Text = "Yes", Value = true });
            DropDowns.Add(new DropDown { Text = "No", Value = false });
        }
```

Then, I bind it in view like following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.DropDowns, "Value", "Text",1),"Select") //last para - OptionLabel
```

On the view, all three parameters are getting display i.e. "Select", "Yes" and "No". But, by default "No" has been selected. If I make "Value" property as integer then it works fine and by default "Select" gets selected, but as mentioned in the code, if I tend to go with bool type then "No" gets selected.

How to get normal behavior when DataValueField is bool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Model:

```
public bool? Value { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
```

This makes a drop down list automatically with 3 states that match the 3 states of a nullable bool: null, true, false. If you require that Value be answered you can use data annotations like so:

Model:

```
[Required]
public bool? Value { get; set; }
```

The takeaway is your model needs to be a real model -- it needs to model the input values from unset to set. If you need to input a `int`, you'll likely want to use a nullable int (so `int?`) and require the value. That way the initial value is null instead of 0. It is similar with other data types except `string` which is already nullable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I guess my question was misunderstood. Currently, with bool value by default "NO" is selected. Instead, I want "Select" which the OptionLabel should be selected.

Comment: I'll let someone else answer that one -- you need to provide the `DropDown` model for them.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to post back the code... :(    I guess, the issue is with lambda expression type. In above code, x=>x.SelectedValue's type is bool. That forces engine to select last "false" value in the provided collection. I ain't sure though!

Comment: Its my inadequate knowledge about DropDownListFor(...) wasted your time. x=>x.SelectedValue which is not set and its default value is false. Hence from the list, it will select any false value. Your nullable solution is gonna be handy here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This doesn't work for us. The default "NOT SET" option with no value won't pass validation.

Comment: @Alexandre I'd suggest posting a new question so it gets looked at by more people. You should get an answer that way.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that, as far as I'm concerned, the example you gave will generate a drop down list that won't pass validation if nothing is selected (null). That's what is happening in my case anyway. Maybe because of a third factor (don't have time to validate further) but I thought it would be useful to add it as a comment if anyone else has the same problem while implementing your solution.

Comment: @Alexandre Ah, super late but yeah, that was kind of the whole point -- if you want to require the value, allow it to be initially null but require it and then they have to answer. If you allow null, then no need for `[Required]`. So this allows null as an initial value but requires an answer.

Answer (score 13):

**ViewModel**

```
public bool flag { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.flag, new List<SelectListItem>()
{
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "True" },
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "False"}
}, "Select.....", new { @id = "flag", @class="form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.flag)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have the `[Required]` data annotation on the model.

Comment: Correct, javascript validation would need to be used.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! I just left out the third parameter "Select....." as I was dealing with a required field so it would always be populated.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had a bunch of these dropdowns on the same page and I thought I'd be clever and reuse the select list, e.g.

```
var YesOrNoTriState = new List<SelectListItem> {
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "" },
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = true.ToString() },
  new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = false.ToString() }
};
```

and in the view

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field1, Model.YesOrNoTriState) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field2, Model.YesOrNoTriState) %>
```

that wasn't working. I initialized a separate select list for each dropdown and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old topic but I thought that for others this might come in handy to know a little background about.

no is selected by default because the default value of a bool is false

if you just set the model to be a 
null-able Bool like this in your view model then it should by default select your default value. :

```
public bool? Value { get; set; }
```

and then you just set your dropdownlist like this in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.DropDowns, "Value", "Text",1),"{Default Select Value}")
```

the result of this should be that when the bool is null the automatically selected option should be your default value `{Default Select Value}`